# SequelizeHostNotFoundError on Cloud functions

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, sequelize.js, google-cloud-functions, compose-db

I am trying to run sequelize on Google Cloud functions, and trying to connect to a remote db hosted on compose.com, but I am getting this error

`

```
 SequelizeHostNotFoundError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND gcp-us-east1-
cpu.2.dblayer.com gcp-us-east1-cpu.2.dblayer.com:16070
at connection.connect.err 
 (/user_code/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres/connection-
  manager.js:95:24)
  at Client.<anonymous> 
 (/user_code/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:203:5)
  at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
  at Connection.emit (events.js:188:7)
  at Socket.<anonymous> 
 (/user_code/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:86:10)
  at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
  at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
  at connectErrorNT (net.js:1020:8)
  at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
  at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:122:9)
```

`

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.
I couldn't connect to an external API or address if I wasn't subscribed to a paid plan on Google Cloud Functions.